# Delete Files of multiple File types in c#

Tags: c#

I have the following solution to delete a single file type with only one extension; however I am trying to find a way to incorporate multiple file extensions, for example: `.wma, .mp3, .wav`

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\");
FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles("*.mpeg")
                     .Where(p => p.Extension == ".mpeg").ToArray();
foreach (FileInfo file in files)
    try
    {
        file.Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal;
        File.Delete(file.FullName);
    }
    catch { }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well that's just a matter of changing your condition to be "where the extension is any one of a set" and removing the pattern from the `GetFiles` call. Also note that you don't need to call `ToArray()` - just iterate over the results:

```
var extensions = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
    { ".wma", ".mp3", ".wav" };

var files = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\").GetFiles()
                                     .Where(p => extensions.Contains(p.Extension));
foreach (var file in files)
{
    // try/catch if you really need, but I'd recommend catching a more
    // specific exception
    file.Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal;
    File.Delete(file.FullName);    
}
```

Comment: Thank You, A tangent question, could this method be applied to the copying of files?

Comment: @dames: Well it's just selecting the filenames, really - what you do with them is up to you.

Comment: Well I would like to select the files and move them to specific locations, however doing it in this approach where I incorporate all the formats

Comment: @dames: It's not really clear what you're asking for - but I suggest you try what you can and then ask a new and specific question if you really need to.

Answer (score 6):

You can store the allowed extensions in a collection and use `Enumerable.Contains`:

```
string[] allowedExtensions = { ".mpeg", ".wma", ".mp3", ".wave" };
FileInfo[] files = di.EnumerateFiles()
 .Where(p => allowedExtensions.Contains(p.Extension, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
 .ToArray();
```

Note that i've used [`DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383574%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is probably more efficient in this case since it does not need to load all file-names into memory(as `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles`) before it can start processing. `StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` should be self-explaining.

Comment: Felt the need to point out that I thought you were saying GetFiles loads all the files into memory before it returns but it just returns the filenames.

Answer (score 5):

You can have extension in an array and then get **all** files from the directory and compare each extension like:

```
string[] fileExtensions = new[] { ".wma", ".mp3", ".wave" };
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\");
FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles()
                     .Where(p => fileExtensions.Contains(p.Extension)).ToArray();
```

If you want case insensitive comparison then use:

```
FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles()
                     .Where(p => fileExtensions.Contains
                    (p.Extension, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
di.GetFiles().Where(
    p => p.Extension == ".mpeg" || 
    p.Extension == ".mp3" || 
    p.Extension == ".wave");
```